# Self-complementary graphs and planarity

Tags: graph-theory

Are there infinitely many self-complementary graphs?

If yes:
Then, are there infinitely many self-complementary planar graphs?

Comment: For examples of arbitrarily large self complementary graphs see paley graphs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are infinitely many self-complementary graphs. A way to construct some is the following:

Choose the self-complementary path-graph $P_3=(\{1,2,3,4\},E)$ and a number $n\in \Bbb N$. Construct the graph $P_3^n$ from $P_3$ where each vertex $v\in \{1,2,3,4\}$ is replaced by $n$ vertices $v_1,...,v_n$ and there is an edge between vertices $v_i$ and $w_j$ if and only if $vw\in E$ or $v=w\in\{1,3\}$. This graph is self-complementary.

[image]

It is like replacing any edge by a complete bipartite graph and every second vertex by a complete (or edge-less) graph. Of course, for $n\geq 3$ this will be not planar. By the way, the right graph in the picture is planar.

Comment: nice diagrams, how did you make them?

Comment: @Tac Just Inkscape ;)

Comment: The second graph in your figure does not appear to be self-complementary -- it has only $12$ edges which is less than half of the $28$ edges the complete graph on $8$ vertices has.

Comment: @HenningMakholm You were right, I fixed it. It is still generalizable to other self-complementary graphs, but it takes more explanations and I do not want to make the answer more complicated than necessary.

Comment: There is another construction to get self complementary graph.. Which is.. If G is any graph... Let G1=G4=G and G2=G3=Gc(complement of G) and then H= G1+G2+G3+G4 is a self complementary graph

Comment: In general, the [lexicographic product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographic_product_of_graphs) of two self-complementary graphs is self-complementary.

Comment: I'm more conserned about Self Complementary Planar Graphs....so any idea of any kind of construction to get self complementary Planar Graphs

Comment: @user471196 What exactly do you want to know? The other answer of Tac anready contained that there are only finitelys many such graphs. Do you need examples or a complete enumeration?

Comment: Examples would be helpful... And if we can find a enumeration for it... It would be really great

Comment: @user471196 I recommend you starting a new question with this exact wording, because this question (as worded) is answered, you even already accepted an answer!

Comment: Thank U very much.... It was really helpful 

Answer (score 4):

A self complementary graph on $n$ vertices has $n(n-1)/4$ edges.

A planar graph on $n$ vertices has at most $3n-6$ edges.

If we have a self-complementary planar graph then we have $n^2-n\geq 12n-24\implies n^2-13n+24\implies n\leq 10$.

Since $n^2-n$ must be a multiple of $4$ this gives:

$n=0,1,4,5,8,9$

Comment: So there cannot be a self complementary planar graph?

Comment: @user471196 $P_3$ is a self-complementary planar graph. But ther can only be finitely many.