# Graph Theory Isomorphism

Tags: graph-theory, graph-isomorphism

Are there any graphs that are isomorphic to its complement? I'm not sure if I can consider just a vertex A with no edges to be the graph and its complement A' to also have no edges which would make them isomorphic to each other.

Comment: The cycle graph on $5$ vertices?

Comment: An infinite number: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-complementary_graph

Answer (score 5):

There are in fact *many* graphs which are isomorphic to their complement. For example, there are more than 9 billion such graphs of order 20. See http://oeis.org/A000171 for more enumerative results.

In fact, there are infinitely many self-complementary graphs, as is explained well in an answer to this previous M.SE [question.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2390138/self-complementary-graph-and-planar-graph)

Answer (score 1):

Try the path graph $P_4$ (edges of complement shown below in red)

[image]